# Do I have to unmount the drive when using dd command?

Tags: 14.04, dd

I have a 60 GB SSD where my Ubuntu installation and home folder is and a 1 TB HDD that I used to use as storage device (movies, music..). I have decided to sell the 1 TB drive but before I do that I want to completely erase all data on it or at least make it unrecoverable by most software out there. What I want to do is the following:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdc
```

and then quick format the drive using Disks utility.

My question is this: do I need to unmount the `/dev/sdc` before I proceed with the `dd` command?

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/21501/possibility-of-recovering-files-from-a-dd-zero-filled-hard-disk

Comment: Just umount it.  That's always the best policy.  That way no programs will be trying to access it while dd is wiping their data away.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Is there an option where I note that this question has been answered or do I leave it as is?

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero` would possibly be much faster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's possible (checked in this moment) but it's highly advisable to `umount` the device before a `dd`.

---

This may be not a problem in your special case `if=/dev/urandom`, but in other cases:

If is some activity on that partition during the `dd` command, there is no guarantee that you partition isn't broken.

Comment: I was too impatient to wait for your answers so I did it anyway - I've let dd do the work on the mounted device. It didn't give me any errors while I was running it but it did suggest a MASSIVE time needed to complete the task. The way I found out about the time is that I installed a package called "pv" that gave me a number of neat little stats about the progress of dd command. So the command I entered looked like this: sudo dd if=/dev/urandom | pv | sudo dd of=/dev/sdc

Comment: The writing of random data peaked at 13MB/s which would make total time for 1TB drive abound 24h. That's a lot of time.

Comment: if you just want to make your data unrecoverable, why not use /dev/zero? 1TB should only take a couple of minutes.

Comment: If there is a swap partition, you can use the swapoff command.
    swapoff /dev/sda2
if sda2 is the swap area

Answer (score 1):

You should boot into a Live USB and unmount the disk you are trying to erase. If you absolutely must, you can try remounting the root filesystem as read-only using Alt+SysRQ+u, then use `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX` where /dev/sdX is your disk. You really should consider using a Live USB though, since it is MUCH safer.

Answer (score 0):

The srm (secure-remove) utility provides several options/patterns for overwriting previous disk contents.

Some of these options are secure enough to ensure that forensic disk scans will not be able to recover the previous files; but: more security = lengthier overwrite process.

To install srm type:

```
sudo apt install secure-delete
```

to use:

```
srm szFileName
```