# Accidently ran sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX . Can I recover?

Tags: 12.04

SO I accidently zeroed out my main drive. Meant to put sdb and put sda by mistake. :(

Computer is still on, anyway I can recover? I know if I restart I'm screwed.

Comment: Backup. Now. If you can. I think that the fact that it's still working is a lucky accident, as soon as the filesystem need to check the superblock it will break.

Comment: go ahead and re-install. You can pull your data from the live usb.

Comment: In case you interrupted `dd` while running there may be remnants of  some of your files that were not yet overwritten. Only those files can be recovered (e.g. with TestDisk/PhotoRec). All other files will be lost. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/94421/is-there-a-way-to-recover-files-from-a-storage-device-partially-overwritten-with

Comment: According to [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/21507/400278) answer it is impossible to recover data from that drive once it is gone.

Comment: yeah it only ran for 2.7GB out of 480GB. First thing I did was git commit and push my school work, luckily. I already have it backed up, I'm just scared that grub will get messed up since grub is not backed up only my ext4 partition

Comment: @JeanLuis The rest of the disk should be unaffected then :)

Comment: @JeanLuis Your grub might be messed up but if worst comes to worst you can reinstall Ubuntu and then just put your data back on the drive.

Comment: I might just not ever turn the computer off then.... lol

Comment: You should be able to recover what hasn't been overwritten with a tool like TestDisk.

Comment: So GRUB was destroyed, but I was able to recover my Windows and Ubuntu partiiton. Yay :)